# Get Intermediate hops using InetAddress.isReachable method

Tags: java, network-programming, ping, icmp, traceroute

InetAddress.isReachable(NetworkInterface , int ttl, int timeOut) return true if the specific address is reachable in number of hops from ttl, other wise false.

Can I also know from which IP address it got the success or failure message? I meant can I have the IP of intermediate hops from which isReachable gets success or failure resposne.

Comment: Keep in mind that routes change often. Even if you determined the route tree the next time you made the call you would likely get a different answer. At least on a WAN, any answer you get needs to be treated with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yeah I get it. But still I wanted to see the performance from customer end.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says;

> A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.

Basically, no. As TCP/IP is designed, you're in no way guaranteed to get hop-by-hop reachability information by using normal ICMP/TCP transmissions, so there is no reliable way to get that information.

The "traceroute" command can get semi reliable information on a hop by hop basis by setting TTL on the packets it sends, but isReachable is a "quick and dirty" way to check reachability and does not use this technique.